# Connect to API and send back a message with Flask app

Tags: python-3.x, flask, server, chatbot

I have a flask app deployed to Heroku and would like to receive text from Chatfuel (bot building platform) and send back texts in return.

Now, what I did is to use my heroku app as a web-hook, so that Chatfuel can make a simple GET or POST query to my API. The problem is that I have no experience with Flask or APIs, so I am not sure about how my app can receive information (in json format) and send it back to chatfuel.

This is what I wrote so far:

```
import os
import sys
import json

import requests
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def verify():
# when the endpoint is registered as a webhook, it must echo back
    # the 'hub.challenge' value it receives in the query arguments
    if request.args.get("hub.mode") == "subscribe" and request.args.get("hub.challenge"):
        if not request.args.get("hub.verify_token") == os.environ["VERIFY_TOKEN"]:
            return "Verification token mismatch", 403
        return request.args["hub.challenge"], 200

    return "Hello world", 200

@app.route("/json", methods=['GET','POST'])
def json():
    url = "chatfuel_api"
    data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))

    if request.json:
        mydata = request.json  
        return "Thanks",200

    else:
        return "no json received"

@app.route('/hello', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def api_echo():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return "ECHO: GET\n",200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The `verify()` function works, as I see an 'Hello world' message if I run the app locally. However, both `json()` and `api_echo()` don't work, and when my server receives a get or post request from chatfuel, it returns a 404 error.

As you can see, I really have a lot of confusion, and your help would be really invaluable.

Thanks

Comment: Please send the log or traceback.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am not sure how to get that on heroku. Is it by running  `heroku logs -t`?

Comment: This is what I see when I run heroku (I have substituted the real host, request and fwd values. `up` is the name of the attribute I am interested in): `at=info method=GET path="/webhook?up=Hh&up=Hh" host=x.herokuapp.com request_id=y fwd="z" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=404 bytes=386 protocol=https`

Comment: The log said Chatfuel send a get request to `/webhook` endpoint. But there is no route defined to handle it in your application. Your application is only has ability to response to `/`, `/json`, `/hello`.

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks for the comment. Would you mind expanding on that? How can I define a route to handle the webhook in my application? Should I just use the name of the web-hook like this:  `@app.route("/webhook", methods=['GET','POST'])`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And handle all logic in there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have registered the proper webhook url with Chatfuel. For the code you currently have, to hit the json endpoint the url would be `https://www.your_server.com/json`

The verify route looks like the hub challenge FB sends, so you would have to register the root of your site (that is, with your current code) with FB to hit the verify function. That url would look like this `https://www.your_site.com/`